# Why must a probability measure map to $[0,1]$ and not $[0,R]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In probability theory, a probability measure $P$ is defined as a mapping from the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ of a sample space $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$.

As this is intrinsically just a mapping to a scalar under the restrictions that $P(\emptyset)=0$ and $P(\Omega) = 1$, why is the range $[0,1]$ chosen? Why not $[0,0.5]$ or $[0,999999999]$?

Most books seem to skip the explanation for this choice of range and it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Probability is not intrinsically “just a mapping”. It has certain convenient *properties*. At its most basic level, probability is measuring a frequency of occurrences for an outcome of some kind of experiment and we have features like additivity of disjoint events, multiplicativity of   unrelated (“independent”) events, and complementary events have probabilities that add up to $1$.  Do you have useful rules for indep. events with a system of probabilities in $[0,1/2]$?  If you never want to do nontrivial calculations with probabilities then you can use old-fashioned percents in $[0,100]$.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a fair question.

Comment: It's a fair question. My 2 cents are that we need this for the formula $$P=\frac{\text{favorable cases}}{\text{total cases}}, $$ which is true for finite probability spaces. If the total probability was, say, $2$, then the formula would have a factor of $2$ in front of it.